# Issue with CosmosDB LINQQuery and ContinuationToken

Tags: c#, azure, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem doing a CosmosDb query with LINQ. The main problem comes up when I add the ORDER BY clause while removing it the query run smooth. Adding the ORDER BY clause makes the second iteration of the query, when I add the continuationToken, throw an Exception.
This is the continuationToken (I removed the token because is very long):

```json
[
    {
        "compositeToken": {
        "token":"+RID:~njgzAO5qBgzIGQAAAAAACA...",
            "range": {
                "min": "",
                "max": "05C1E0"
            }
        },
        "orderByItems": [
            {
                "item": 74.80897
            }
        ],
        "rid": "njgzAO5qBgzIGQAAAAAACA==",
        "skipCount": 0,
        "filter": "true"
    }
]
```

This is the message fron the exception:

**Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 5a692073-43db-4050-a856-d3d7cae01503; Reason: ({"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":245,"end":246},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near ','."}]}
ActivityId: 5a692073-43db-4050-a856-d3d7cae01503, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum, Windows/10.0.22621 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.31.4);**

Below the method I use for vreatin tyhe IQuerable:

```cs
private async Task<IQueryable<TDatabase>> _GetQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpression, bool disc, TDatabase s, PagedItem pagedItem = null, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderThenByExpressionPaged = null, bool pagedDesc = false)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    var queryDefinition = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<TDatabase>(continuationToken: pagedItem.ContinuationToken);//, linqSerializerOptions: LinqOptions);
    IQueryable<TDatabase> queryable = queryDefinition.Where(a => true);

    Expression<Func<TDatabase, bool>> predicateDb = mapper.Map<Expression<Func<TDatabase, bool>>>(predicate);
    Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>> orderByExpressionDB = mapper.Map<Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>>>(orderByExpression);

    if (predicateDb != null)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where<TDatabase>(predicateDb);
    }

    IOrderedQueryable<TDatabase> OrderBy = null;
    if (orderByExpression != null)
    {
        if (disc)
            OrderBy = queryable.OrderByDescending(orderByExpressionDB);
        else
            OrderBy = queryable.OrderBy(orderByExpressionDB);
        queryable = OrderBy;
    }
    if (orderThenByExpressionPaged != null)
    {
        Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>> orderByExpressionThenByDB = mapper.Map<Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>>>(orderThenByExpressionPaged);
        if (pagedDesc)
            OrderBy = OrderBy.ThenByDescending(orderByExpressionThenByDB);
        else
            OrderBy = OrderBy.ThenBy(orderByExpressionThenByDB);
        queryable = OrderBy;
    }
    return queryable;
}
```

I tried to remove the ContinuationToken in the debugger and the query runs fine but returns the previous result.

Comment: How is this queryable used?

Comment: Have you tried updating your client sdk?

Comment: @StephenCleary 
var feedIterator = queryable.ToFeedIterator();
var queryResult = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
The package MIcrosoft.Azure.Cosmos is updated: 3.35.4

Answer (score -1):

**`GetItemLinqQueryable()`** method is used to create a LINQ query which allows to retrieve the data from the container. `orderByExpression` and `orderThenByExpressionPaged` are used for sorting the query.

`orderByExpression` is defined using `Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>>`, it is used to sort the results by **Age** property and **PagingItem** object is used to handle the pagination. In this **ContinuationToken** property is used to store and pass from one iteration of the query to next iteration of the query.

In your code you have not used `allowSynchronousQueryExecution:true`, which allows query execution synchronously and not using this will give a different error. The error which you are getting seems to be a syntax error you can reuse my code for achieving desired output.

I just used order by filtering to show how the **ORDER BY** clause works in the below code.

**Below Is the code I tried with**

```cs
private async Task<IQueryable<TDatabase>> _GetQuery(
    Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>> orderByExpression,
    bool desc,
    PagingItem pagedItem = null,
    Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>> orderThenByExpressionPaged = null,
    bool pagedDesc = false)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;

    var queryDefinition = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<TDatabase>(continuationToken: pagedItem?.ContinuationToken,
        allowSynchronousQueryExecution: true
        );

    IOrderedQueryable<TDatabase> queryable;

    if (desc)
        queryable = queryDefinition.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression);
    else
        queryable = queryDefinition.OrderBy(orderByExpression);

    if (orderThenByExpressionPaged != null)
    {
        if (pagedDesc)
            queryable = queryable.ThenByDescending(orderThenByExpressionPaged);
        else
            queryable = queryable.ThenBy(orderThenByExpressionPaged);
    }

    return queryable;
}

public async Task MainMethod()
{
    string orderByPropertyName = "Age"; 
    Expression<Func<TDatabase, object>> orderByExpression = CreateOrderByExpression(orderByPropertyName);

    var queryable = await _GetQuery(orderByExpression, true, null);

    var results = queryable.ToList();

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.GetType().GetProperty("Id")?.GetValue(item)}, Name: {item.GetType().GetProperty("Name")?.GetValue(item)}, Age: {item.GetType().GetProperty("Age")?.GetValue(item)}, Field: {item.GetType().GetProperty("Field")?.GetValue(item)}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```js
Id: 2, Name: Balaji, Age: 25, Field: NON-IT
Id: 1, Name: Pavan, Age: 24, Field: IT
Id: 3, Name: Pavan Balaji, Age: 23, Field: Software
```

Comment: This answer doesn’t identify any issues in the OP’s code - it’s only your code. It’s also filled with explanations for every step - steps the OP already knows about. Same pattern as your other answers - same “auto generated content” appearance.

Comment: David I edited the solution and shared the code along with it. As Leanardo mentioned in his question he's getting syntax error. The intention from my end was to provide a code which Leanardo can use to get the desired result.